# Nのすべての倍数を表示したい

Tags: c

キーボードから正の整数Nを読み込み、1から100までのすべてのNの倍数とその個数を表示するプログラムを作りたいのですが、すべてのNの倍数の表示方法がわかりません。
とりあえず第一段階として、Nの倍数の個数を表示するプログラムを作ることはできたので、それを下に示します。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,baisu;
    int kosu=0;
    printf("倍数は： "); scanf("%d",&baisu);
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
        if(i%baisu==0)kosu+=1;
    }
    printf("0以上100以下の%dの倍数の個数は%dです\n",baisu,kosu);
    return 0;
}
```

実行結果

```
$ ./a.out
倍数は：  4
0以上100以下の4の倍数の個数は25です
```

上記のプログラムに何を付け足したら、すべてのNの倍数が表示されるのでしょうか。ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: その`if`文が真の場合、`i`を出力する？

Comment: もしかして、「倍数は：4, .......」と列挙したいということでしょうか。でなければ現在のループ処理でほとんど答えが出ていると思いますが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9月15日、[同じ質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70421/%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93/70423#70423)をしましたね。その質問と回答を見て、OPはC言語の初心者だと思い、詳しく説明するほうがいいと考えます。

すべてのNの倍数を表示するには、以下のコメント付き行を追加します。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,baisu;
    int kosu=0;
    printf("倍数は： "); scanf("%d",&baisu);
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
        if(i%baisu==0){
            printf("%d\n", i);    // この行を追加
            kosu+=1;
        }
    }
    printf("0以上100以下の%dの倍数の個数は%dです\n",baisu,kosu);
    return 0;
}
```

Nの倍数の個数をカウントするために、`i%baisu`の結果が0か0でないかをテストします。その結果が0の場合、`i`はNの倍数だと判断し、個数`kosu`をインクリメントしますね。その時、`i`を出力し、すべてのNの倍数が表示されます。

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。指示通りプログラムしたら、きちんとコンパイルできました。printf("%d\n",i); のたった一文を付け足すだけで、目的のプログラムを作成できるとは思いもよりませんでした。初歩的な質問に丁寧に答えていただき、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

1～100の値のNの倍数ですから

```
for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
　　// ここでiとbaisuにより計算
　　// それを表示する。
}
```

となると思います。

Answer (score 0):

Nの倍数を計算するのを繰り返して倍数が101以上になったら終了するという考え方の別解です。
正直なところ誤差ではあるのでしょうが、Nに入る数値次第でループ回数が減るのでたぶん経済的だと思います。

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long int StrToL(const char *const sourceStr);

int main(void) {
  enum { bufSize = 8 };
  char buf[bufSize] = "";
  fprintf(stderr, "%s", "正の整数を入力してください: ");
  fgets(buf, bufSize, stdin);
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; // chomp
  long int base = StrToL(buf);

  if (base < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "% ld %s\n", base, "は正の整数ではありません。");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "%ld %s", base, "の1から100までの倍数は");
  }

  int count = 0;
  if (base < 101) {
    while (base * ++count < 101) {
      fprintf(stderr, "% ld", base * count);
    }
    --count;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "%s%d%s\n", (count > 0) ? " の" : "", count, "個です。");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

long int StrToL(const char *const sourceStr) {
  char *unsafeChar;
  errno = 0;
  enum { OCTAL = 8, DECIMAL = 10, HEXA = 16 };
  const long number = strtol(sourceStr, &unsafeChar, DECIMAL);

  if (unsafeChar == sourceStr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: not a decimal number\n", sourceStr);
  } else if ('\0' != *unsafeChar) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: extra characters at end of input: %s\n", sourceStr,
            unsafeChar);
  } else if ((LONG_MIN == number || LONG_MAX == number) && ERANGE == errno) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s out of range of type long\n", sourceStr);
  } else if (number > INT_MAX) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%ld greater than INT_MAX\n", number);
  } else if (number < INT_MIN) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%ld less thatn INT_MIN\n", number);
  }

  return number;
}
```